# Which machine learning algorithim should i implement for detecting document type?

Tags: python, machine-learning

We have requirement that we get different type of documents from client like student admission document, marksheet etc. So we want to create an algorithm which identify which document it is. So for this we choose some specific keyword to identify the document type like if admission documents have keywords like `fee`, `admission` etc . And `marksheet` documents keyword like `marks`, `grade` etc. So Here we can predict document type by comparing keywords frequency.

For this above requirement which algorithm should implement? I was planning to implement multinomial naive base algorithm. But I can not fit my data in to it.

FYI.. I am using python sklearn module.

Can you please anyone tell me which algorithm should suitable for above requirement. If possible can you also please provide an example with code so that i can easily figure out the solution?

Comment: In what form do you get the document? scanned, after OCR, binary file?

Comment: Image document but i can extract data by using OCR.

Comment: I know it is sort of state of the art to throw a neural network at everything, but isn't there something really smart that you could try first? :) People solved what you are trying to do years ago when there was no AI available. Are the forms standardized? Is there a common header, logo, whatever, where you could derive the type from using "normal" image processing?

Comment: Actually I am new in this machine learning so i was not getting proper way to implement this. After study so many blog and  and video, I got my solution. Thanks for sharing your thought.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You are looking for **Topic Modeling** solution and there are plenty of it to solve the problem. via python and scikit-learn i recommend you to take a look at [this article](https://medium.com/mlreview/topic-modeling-with-scikit-learn-e80d33668730)

Comment: Thanks for  sharing your knowledge. I solved my issue by referring https://www.ritchieng.com/machine-learning-multinomial-naive-bayes-vectorization/